# REGex in python does not extract right

Tags: python, regex

```
test = """1d48bac (TAIL, ticket: TAG-AB123-6, origin/master) Took example of 123        
       6f2c5f9 (ticket: TAG-CD456) Took example of 456
       9aa5436 (ticket: TAG-EF567-3) Took example of 6789"""
```

I want to write a regex in python that will extract just the tag- i.e.output should be

```
[TAG-AB123-6, TAG-CD456, TAGEF567-3]
```

I tired a regex

```
print re.findall("TAG-[A-Z]{0,9}\d{0,5}(-\d{0,2})?", test)
```

but this gives me

```
['-6', '', '-3']
```

what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4):

Your optional capturing group needs to be made a non-capturing one:

```
>>> print re.findall(r"TAG-[A-Z]{0,9}\d{0,5}(?:-\d{0,2})?", test)
['TAG-AB123-6', 'TAG-CD456', 'TAG-EF567-3']
```

`findall` returns all capturing groups. If there are no capturing groups it will return all the matches.

Answer (score 0):

In addition, note that you can also take advantage of this behaviour *(the fact that `re.findall` returns a list of captures if any instead of the whole match)*. This allows to describe all the context around the target substring and to easily extract the part you want:

```
>>> re.findall(r'ticket: ([^,)]*)', test)
['TAG-AB123-6', 'TAG-CD456', 'TAG-EF567-3']
```